# How to use DevicePolicyManager.ClearApplicationUserData

Tags: c#, android, device-owner

I'm writing device-owner app in c#(in visual studio environment), and i need to create function that clears data of another applications.
I've googled how to use DevicePolicyManager.ClearApplicationUserData in c#, but only useful thing i found is:

```
private void clearApplicationUserData(String packageName) {
    mDevicePolicyManager.clearApplicationUserData(mAdminComponentName, packageName, new MainThreadExecutor(), (__, succeed) -> showToast(succeed ? R.string.clear_app_data_success : R.string.clear_app_data_failure, packageName));
}
```

(source: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/afwsamples/testdpc/policy/PolicyManagementFragment.java ; line: 3382-3391)

I converted this from java to c# and got this error:
Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener' because it is not a delegate type

```
public static void ClearApplicationUserData(string pkg)
        {
            IExecutor executor = Executors.NewSingleThreadExecutor();
            devicePolicyManager.ClearApplicationUserData(Admin, pkg, executor, (strPKG,boolSUCCESS) => Log.Debug("ClearApplicationUserData", boolSUCCESS ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL"));
        }
```

Looks like this should work, but i don't know how to make 'listener' non-null

```
public static void ClearApplicationUserData(string pkg)
        {
            IExecutor executor = Executors.NewSingleThreadExecutor();
            DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener listener;
            devicePolicyManager.ClearApplicationUserData(Admin, pkg, executor, listener);
        }
```

I've tried:

```
devicePolicyManager.ClearApplicationUserData(Admin, pkg, executor, (DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener)((strPKG, boolSUCCESS) => Log.Debug("ClearApplicationUserData", "-")));
```

Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener' because it is not a delegate type

```
devicePolicyManager.ClearApplicationUserData(Admin, pkg, executor, (Action<DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener>)((strPKG, boolSUCCESS) => Log.Debug("ClearApplicationUserData", "-")));
```

Error CS1593 Delegate 'Action<DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener>' does not take 2 arguments

```
devicePolicyManager.ClearApplicationUserData(Admin, pkg, executor, (Action<DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener>)((AAAA) => Log.Debug("ClearApplicationUserData", "-")));
```

Error CS1503 Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Action<Android.App.Admin.DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener>' to 'Android.App.Admin.DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener?'

```
devicePolicyManager.ClearApplicationUserData(Admin, pkg, executor, delegate { (DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener)((AAAA) => Log.Debug("ClearApplicationUserData", "-")); });
```

Error CS1660 Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener' because it is not a delegate type

May be helpful:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#clearApplicationUserData(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.OnClearApplicationUserDataListener)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.OnClearApplicationUserDataListener

```
[Register("clearApplicationUserData", "(Landroid/content/ComponentName;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;Landroid/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager$OnClearApplicationUserDataListener;)V", "GetClearApplicationUserData_Landroid_content_ComponentName_Ljava_lang_String_Ljava_util_concurrent_Executor_Landroid_app_admin_DevicePolicyManager_OnClearApplicationUserDataListener_Handler", ApiSince = 28)]
public virtual void ClearApplicationUserData(ComponentName? admin, string? packageName, IExecutor? executor, IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener? listener);
....
....
....
[Register("android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager$OnClearApplicationUserDataListener", "", "Android.App.Admin.DevicePolicyManager/IOnClearApplicationUserDataListenerInvoker", ApiSince = 28)]
        public interface IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener : IJavaObject, IDisposable, IJavaPeerable
        {
            [Register("onApplicationUserDataCleared", "(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V", "GetOnApplicationUserDataCleared_Ljava_lang_String_ZHandler:Android.App.Admin.DevicePolicyManager/IOnClearApplicationUserDataListenerInvoker, Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", ApiSince = 28)]
            void OnApplicationUserDataCleared(string? packageName, bool succeeded);
        }

        public class ClearApplicationUserDataEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public ClearApplicationUserDataEventArgs(string? packageName, bool succeeded);

            public string? PackageName { get; }
            public bool Succeeded { get; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
public class ClearApplicationUserDataListener : Java.Lang.Object, DevicePolicyManager.IOnClearApplicationUserDataListener
{
    public void OnApplicationUserDataCleared(string packageName, bool succeeded) { }
}
public static void ClearApplicationUserData(string pkg)
{
    IExecutor executor = Executors.NewSingleThreadExecutor();
    var listener = new ClearApplicationUserDataListener();
    devicePolicyManager.ClearApplicationUserData(Admin, pkg, executor, listener);           
}
```